# IE dropdowns cut off NON-fixed widths

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some  boxes that are getting cut off for no apparent reason but when I click on them either right click or left click they expand back to normal. Please see screenshots.

[image]

When I click the dropdown:

[image]

HTML:

```
<select id="attribute_values_1903" name="attribute_values_1903">
<option value="">Please select a value</option><option value="80469">12” (305mm)</option><option value="75549">18" (457mm)</option><option value="75548">20" (508mm)</option><option value="75935">24" (610mm)</option><option value="76295">28" (711mm)</option><option value="75528">30" (762mm)</option><option value="75915">36" (914mm)</option><option value="75907">42" (1067mm)</option><option value="75900">48" (1219mm)</option><option value="75768">54" (1372mm)</option><option value="75767">60" (1524mm)</option><option value="75930">66" (1676mm)</option><option value="76281">72" (1829mm)</option><option value="78762">78" (1981mm)</option><option value="76948">84" (2134mm)</option><option value="80467">96” (2438mm)</option>
</select>
```

CSS: I'm using the YUI reset, fonts and base as well as this for my own css

```
select 
{ 
    border:1px solid @defaultLightGrey;
    padding:1px;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Code

**EDIT #2:** It looks like I'm having the same issue thats going on here except I'm loading the options with KnockoutJS. [See other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option)

Comment: Could you post the html or css you're using to render these?  It would definitely help!

Comment: try add zoom: 1; to css to avoid strange "hasLayout" bug

Comment: with an animate effect the 'issue' could actually look... sweet! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Deferring to http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/, is it because you specified a short width for the select element, but have longer option elements within them, so your option elements are being clipped?

If this is an IE specific problem, you can turn to IE conditional comments to specify styles just for IE to fix the problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Find and remove the width setting for the `select` element. The code posted does not contain such a setting, and neither does the YUI reset code at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/#code and using them the described behavior does not appear. So the problem is in some code not included or mentioned.

Setting e.g. `select { width: 30px }` causes the behavior described in the question, so something like that probably the explanation.

Comment: The dropdown is contined within a table that has width="100%" on it. Could that be the cause? The thing I don't get is that there about 10 other drop downs in that same table that work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ryan, there’s hardly any way to make useful guesses on the specific cause without any access to the code that causes the problem.

Comment: Good point, although there is nowhere I'm setting the width property... Its a generated select box via knockoutjs