# Knockout js + dropdown(select) value binding + IE browsers family

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

It is a badly known issue when selects in IE show only the first letter after dynamical initialization. ([See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option))

But what is the best way to re-render dropdowns after data binding via knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't seen this bug before. You could do something like.

```
<select data-bind="options: youroptions, value: somevalue, visible: !loading()"
</select>
```

Then in your code

```
self.loading(true);
doAjax(function(result) {
    self.youroptions(result);
    self.loading(false);
});
```

This would do as the fix suggests. Not very elegant.

Hope this helps.