# Why is select only showing first character of option text in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Select only showing first character of option text in IE 9

Using click on div event adding option, only the first character is shown.

The problem occurs in IE 9. FF and Chrome is doing it ok.

Works in JQuery 1.3.2 but not above.

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5F2r/25/

Or

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="btn">insert option</button><div id="container"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").append("<select class='category-select root' style='width:100px' />");  
    $("#btn").click(function(){    
       $(".root").append("<option>none</option>");
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't replicate the error. This fiddle works fine in IE8 on my computer: http://jsfiddle.net/q5F2r/4/

Comment: @aaberg I´ve updated the question with new code example. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Tried your fiddle. Works fine in IE8 on my computer.

Comment: Please try it in IE9 with browsermode set to IE 8.. I cant get it to work here. But in clean IE 8 it works .. sorry once again! I´ve updated question with IE9!

Comment: At work we still use ol' IE8, so I could test it with IE9. I have now testet it on my home computer with IE9, and I get the same error as you. Very strange. I will post here, if I find a solution.

Comment: Once you remove the dynamic select creation, to static html(declare it inside div container) it works fine. Do not know why..

Comment: @aaberg nice that you experience the same :-)

Comment: @Anand yep and if I remove the button click and run it all in $(document).ready it is also showing up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. Apparently it has been [discussed before on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option). It's weird that Microsoft can't fix this kind of bug, before they release IE10!!

Well. The solution is a real hack. You can force IE to redraw the <select>, by setting the width of the select to something. In this example it is set to its own value. Wonder why every web developer out there hates IE?

http://jsfiddle.net/q5F2r/32/

Comment: Nice Find. I think Microsoft has admitted defeat in terms of war of browser. They are not shipping great finished product. And now in the latest edition of visual studio, you can choose other browser(like Chrome, FF) to debug your code.

Comment: @kasperxb : yeah weird ! its a bug.