# KnockoutJS fire callback after bindings are complete

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

I have a really annoying bug thats outlined here: [<select> only shows first char of selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option) and I need a way to remove the display:none off of my  boxes to avoid this bug. Any suggestions?

Heres the binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: Values, optionsText: 'DisplayNameWithCost', optionsCaption: ControlCaption, selectedOptions: SelectedValues, event: { change: $root.resolveAllAttributeUi }, disable: IsDisabled"></select>
```

EDIT:
I've managed to figure out that its because `selectedOptions: SelectedValues` is blank and it's not selecting anything in IE9.. As for the fix I'm not sure. Here's an example try in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/9CaTa/

Comment: Can you show me your select element? I saw this happen on an application I was working on with IE and I was able to fix it by modifying the binding a bit.

Comment: Knockout already includes [this fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6668405/1287183), but maybe that's not sufficient in your case?

Comment: @MichaelBest - I was hopeful that was going to work but it didn't, I even did it manually through the console and nothing changed still blank <select /> boxes :(

Comment: @MichaelBest - I've figure out whats going on just not how to fix it. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedOptions` is only meant to be used with a multi-select list. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html.

You probably want to use the `value` binding instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/9CaTa/2/

Edit:

`selectedOptions` doesn't work well with `optionsCaption`, but you could make it at least select the first item by default by creating a custom binding that wraps `selectedOptions`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mySelectedOptions = ko.utils.extend({}, ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions);
ko.bindingHandlers.mySelectedOptions.update = function(element) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions.update.apply(this, arguments);
    if (element.selectedIndex === -1)
        element.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Here's your example using this binding: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/9CaTa/3/

I noticed that if I select the caption, the `selected` array will not be cleared. Instead it will have a single `undefined` item. If you didn't want that, you could check for it in your custom update function as well and then clear the array: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/9CaTa/4/

Comment: You are correct, however in the application I'm using it in I have a collection of SelectedValues that are suppose to be used for any control type: radio, select, multi-select, checkboxes etc.

Comment: I've added some suggestions for how you can make `selectedOptions` work with `optionsCaption`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Great work @Michael Best I ended up going with the 2nd option