# select element shows first char only

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a select html element that is populated with jquery inside an ajax call. All seems to work fine, but in IE9 the select box is just showing the first character of the text.

Here is de jsfiddle that reproduces the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/PjDfS/

I'm aware that this same question was asked here [<select> only shows first char of selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option), but the solution doesn't work in my case. ( http://jsfiddle.net/PjDfS/2/ )

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PjDfS/5/

What did I do? In the end I return to the old post answer and change my first approach a little.

To be more clear, leave the original select as 'display: none', and in the end remove the attribute.

Comment: ... this is my accepted answer, but I can't confirm it just now, I need to wait for two days

Answer (score 0):

I think  the problem with IE9 is with the

```
var messageFieldInput = $('#MessageFieldInputTemplate > .messageField-input').clone()
```

Here :

```
var testObj = [];
testObj[0] = {
    text: 'description 1',
    value: 'value 1'
};
testObj[1] = {
    text: 'description 2',
    value: 'value 2'
};

$.get('/echo/json', function (data) {
    var messageFieldInput = $('#MessageFieldInputTemplate > .messageField-input'); //no .clone()
    $('#MessageFieldContainer').append(messageFieldInput);
    messageFieldInput.find('.editor-label').text('Label');

    $.get('/echo/json', function (data) {
        var fieldSelect = messageFieldInput.find('.editor-field > select');            

        $.each(testObj , function (index, item) {
            fieldSelect.append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    'value':item.value,
                    'text':item.text
})
            );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a nice idea but I need to add more than one select element, and without cloning the template element that isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one `option` inside your `select` within the markup, then remove it with script.

It looks like such an option's text somehow 'allocates' horizontal space, and you won't be able to get ajax populated texts that are longer displayed properly..

UPDATE: Just tried, but it's more complicated.. Works only until you keep the original option in place :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it doesn't work... really it's a pretty strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this way seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/PjDfS/4/

Also, I'm not sure if the code is an exact equivalent. Anyway it works so far...

Comment: Ok, after trying to implement this approach in my 'real world' application, it turns out that if you actually use the data returned by the AJAX call it will not work (that means that IE9 will continue showing just the first character)... but the good part is that after a lot of swearing and bad words, i managed to make it work. See my  accepted answer...