# ng-options populated by ajax only displaying first letter in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am experiencing an odd issue in Angular, seemingly only in Internet Explorer 9.

If you check the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/382/

You can see that the 2 selects are populated, but the display in IE seems broken, and only the first letter, 'A' of 'Apple' is selected. All options display when the select is clicked on.

[image: eg].

The code is very simple, I populate the variable that drives the select in the success callback.

```
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.ReasonsChoice_ajax = data;
});
```

The ng-options code for the select is as follows;

```
 <select ng-model="Reason" ng-options="Reason for Reason in ReasonsChoice_ajax"></select>
```

I have noticed that the glitch doesn't happen if I am using a single select element, it is only when I display multiple selects in an ng-repeat that the issue happens.

Comment: seems like possible bug, check issues in github

Answer (score 11):

You are using Angularjs so the answer is like this:

```
<select ng-style="{'width': '100%'}"></select>
```

Note that you don't have to set width as 100%. You can use px instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not address the problem at hand.

Comment: This fixes the problem but it isn't very pretty having to put `ng-style` on all your select tags.

Comment: I tried lots of ways to repaint the element, which is whats needed to fix the IE9 glitch.  Anything that worked for IE9 also broke other browsers.  Finally found this and it works on everything I've tested.  Great idea.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

See [<select> only shows first char of selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option)

We had the same issue and something like what's below got us around it.

```
$("select").css("width", $("select").css("width"));
```

Of course, all of our selects are the same width. You may need to refine the selector to suit your needs. Basically you just need to force IE to repaint the selects one way or another. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/395/).

Comment: Great, thanks! Out of interest, what is the purpose of the $timeout you added to the fiddle you updated?

Comment: For some reason I was thinking it was needed for it to work, but I took it out, and it still works fine, so just ignore that part I guess. That fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/411/

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this same problem in IE 9. The workaround is to only show the select after the ajax data is available. A simple solution in AngularJs is to add follow to the select: ng-show="ReasonsChoice_ajax.length > 0".

```
<select ng-model="Reason" ng-show="ReasonsChoice_ajax.length > 0" ng-options="Reason for Reason in ReasonsChoice_ajax"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

When my project got a very late change in requirements to also support IE9 I didn't want to go back and annotate all of my `<select>` elements or controllers to deal with this problem, so I wrote the following directive to add behavior to all of them automatically:

```
angular.module('xxxxx')
.directive('select',
           ['$log', '$parse', '$timeout', function ($log, $parse, $timeout) {
    var NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP = /^\s*([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+group\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w]*)|(?:\(\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*,\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*\)))\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?$/;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        require: ['select', '?ngModel'],
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, control) {
            var isIE = document.attachEvent,
                match; 

            if (isIE
                && attrs.ngOptions
                && (match = attrs.ngOptions.match(NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP))) {
                var values = $parse(match[7]);
                scope.$watchCollection(values, function () {
                    // Redraw this select element 
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var originalWidth = $(elem).css('width');
                        $(elem).css('width', '0');
                        $(elem).css('width', originalWidth);
                    }, 10);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I tried many of the other proposed solutions but this was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these worked for me, and not "ng-show" as suggested in a similar post, but "ng-if" around spanning element seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's weird but fortunately this is what you want to trigger the select tag again.

```
ng-show="List.length > 0"
```