# Internet Explorer is not getting all data from xml file in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, internet-explorer

This Javascript code works fine in chrome and Firefox, but it only shows the first item of the "School/College" dropdown box in Internet Explorer. Do you guys see anything IE wouldn't like in this code?

HTML:

```
<label>School/College:</label>
       <select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="School_College_RFI__c_contact" id="School_College_RFI__c_contact" size='1'   tabIndex='19'>
               <option value='' selected='selected'></option>
        </select>
<label>Academic Program:</label>
        <select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="Academic_Program_RFI__c" id="Academic_Program_RFI__c" size='1'   tabIndex='20'>
               <option value='' selected='selected'></option></select>
<label>Academic Career:</label>
         <select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="Academic_Career_RFI__c" id="Academic_Career_RFI__c" size='1'   tabIndex='21'>
               <option value='' selected='selected'></option>
         </select>
<label>Academic Plan of Interest:</label>
         <select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c" id="Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c" size='1'   tabIndex='22'>
                <option value='' selected='selected'></option>
          </select>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" id='autocomplete'>
<!-- Dropdowns -->
$jQ(document).ready(function() {

  $jQ.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xmlResponse ) {
      $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact option').remove();
      $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').append('<option>Please Select</option>');
      $jQ(xmlResponse).find('school').each(function(){
        sc = $jQ(this).find('sname').text();
        $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').append('<option value="'+sc+'" >'+sc+'</option>');
        console.log(sc);
      });
    }
  });

  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').change(function(){
    var ap;
    var college = $jQ(this).val();
    $jQ('#Academic_Program_RFI__c option').remove();
    $jQ('#Academic_Career_RFI__c option').remove();
    $jQ('#Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c option').remove();
    $jQ.ajax({
      url: "url",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function( xmlResponse ) {
        $jQ(xmlResponse).find('sname').each(function(){
          if($jQ(this).text() == college){
            $jQ('#Academic_Program_RFI__c').append('<option>Please Select</option>');
            $jQ(this).siblings('academic_program').each(function(){
              ap = $jQ(this).find('pname').text();
              $jQ('#Academic_Program_RFI__c').append('<option value="'+ap+'" >'+ap+'</option>');
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }).trigger('change');

  $jQ('#Academic_Program_RFI__c').change(function(){
    var ac;
    var academic_program = $jQ(this).val();
    $jQ('#Academic_Career_RFI__c option').remove();
    $jQ('#Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c option').remove();
    $jQ.ajax({
      url: "url",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function( xmlResponse ) {
        $jQ(xmlResponse).find('pname').each(function(){
          if($jQ(this).text() == academic_program){
            $jQ('#Academic_Career_RFI__c').append('<option>Please Select</option>');
            $jQ(this).siblings('academic_career').each(function(){
              ac = $jQ(this).find('cname').text();
              $jQ('#Academic_Career_RFI__c').append('<option value="'+ac+'" >'+ac+'</option>');
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }).trigger('change');

  $jQ('#Academic_Career_RFI__c').change(function(){
    var ai;
    var academic_career = $jQ(this).val();
    $jQ('#Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c option').remove();
    $jQ.ajax({
      url: "url",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function( xmlResponse ) {
        $jQ(xmlResponse).find('cname').each(function(){
          if($jQ(this).text() == academic_career){
            $jQ('#Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c').append('<option>Please Select</option>');
            $jQ(this).siblings('academic_plan_of_interest').children('value').each(function(){
              ai = $jQ(this).text();
              $jQ('#Academic_Plan_of_Interest_RFI__c').append('<option value="'+ai+'" >'+ai+'</option>');
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }).trigger('change');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There have been some inherent bugs with IE when it comes to constructing drop downs dynamically. I think it has to do with ability of IE to draw the dropdown. You can fix this two ways:

1. Set the drop down css property of `display` to `none`, construct the drop down and then remove the `display` property.
2. Force IE to construct the select again with a code like `$("select").width($("select").width());`

Read more about this issue here:

1. https://www.getharvest.com/blog/2009/12/dropdown-problems-on-internet-explorer/
2. [<select> only shows first char of selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908494/select-only-shows-first-char-of-selected-option)

EDIT: Here's an example

OPTION 1:

```
$jQ.ajax({
url: "url",
dataType: "xml",
success: function( xmlResponse ) {
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact option').remove();
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').hide();
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').append('<option>Please Select</option>');
  $jQ(xmlResponse).find('school').each(function(){
    sc = $jQ(this).find('sname').text();
    $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').append('<option value="'+sc+'" >'+sc+'</option>');
    console.log(sc);
  });
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').show();
}
});
```

OPTION 2:

```
$jQ.ajax({
url: "url",
dataType: "xml",
success: function( xmlResponse ) {
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact option').remove();
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').append('<option>Please Select</option>');
  $jQ(xmlResponse).find('school').each(function(){
    sc = $jQ(this).find('sname').text();
    $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').append('<option value="'+sc+'" >'+sc+'</option>');
    console.log(sc);
  });
  $jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').width($jQ('#School_College_RFI__c_contact').width());
}
});
```

Note: Not tested. Assuming the code works fine in Firefox and Chrome (as OP said)

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you give an example of how I would implement this in my code? I just want to point out here that the dropdown does not DISPLAY all the values from the xml file in the dropdown.

Comment: Okay. I edited the answer above to give you an idea of how to proceed. As you said this works in Firefox and Chrome, the changes I mentioned shouldn't affect them but help with IE. I didn't test it, so if you face any issues comment here and I'll help you debug it.

Comment: I tried it and it still gave me the same problem. I ended up changing the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I had to practically change the entire code:

```
 window.onload = function () {
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         my_xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
         my_xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     /////////////////////////////

     my_xml.open("GET", 'http://go.miami.edu/rs/universityofmiami/images/Recruitment_Profile_Mapping_Undergraduate_1014.xml', false);
     my_xml.send();
     xml_str = my_xml.responseXML;


     var x = xml_str.getElementsByTagName("sname");


     var min = 12,
         max = 100,
         select = document.getElementById('School_College_RFI__c_contact');

     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         var opt = document.createElement('option');
         opt.value = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         opt.innerHTML = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         select.appendChild(opt);
     }


 };
```